# how to use jquery with in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function() {
     jQuery("body").on("click","#hoverView",function() {        
       var a = jQuery(this).attr("pname")
       var b = jQuery(this). attr("onclick")
       var c = b.split("/");
       var d = c[c.length-1].replace('"','');
       var z = a +   "|"   +   d; 
     })return z
}
```

with the code given above i am trying to pass this value via google tag manger. but i couldn't do it. please help me how to return this value.can we return click event value?

Comment: jQuery is a library made on top of JS. Please try to explain what you wish to achieve instead

Comment: I would learn JavaScript first. Then worry about libraries once you understand what you're doing.

Comment: is this function written properly. i have custom java script variable and want o show click event value

Comment: Written properly? (Also, java script != javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function() {
    var z;
    $("document").on("click","#hoverView", function(){        
        var a = $(this).attr("pname");
        var b = $(this). attr("onclick");
        var c = b.split("/");
        var d = c[c.length-1].replace('"','');
        z = a +   "|"   +   d; 
    });
    return z;
}
```

Or, simply
Add an onlick event Lister to the hoverview,
    onclick="functionName"
As a tag to the element.

Comment: Why should this be tried? May you add an explanation to this code dump?

Comment: i have tried this.but not working is there any anoyhet way?

Comment: He has mixed a lot of `;` --- semicolons in his code. Further see the position of the variable and it's declaration :)

Comment: can you please help me how  to write jquery within custom java script of goolt tag manager

Comment: @NimishMain I have added another option to the answer.

Comment: Remember you need to add the script src tag

Comment: can u write entire code and share with me? as i m in a learning phase

Answer (score 0):

you can use like that

var temp = "";

$(document).ready(funciton(){

```
 $("body").on("click","#hoverView",function()
  {        
     var a = jQuery(this).attr("pname")
     var b = jQuery(this). attr("onclick")
     var c = b.split("/");``
     var d = c[c.length-1].replace('"','');
     var z = a +   "|"   +   d; 
     temp = z;
 }); });
```

Comment: I would recommend editing this answer. Add an explanation to the code?

Comment: how can i return value?

Comment: you can't return but you can access temp variable because of temp is now global variable.

Comment: are you understand it ? where you want to access return value use temp variable it will return z value Please check and let me know.

Comment: have you seen var temp = ""; i have defined to of the code which is global variable and "z" value put in temp variable so we can access temp variable any where in page .